# Excel calculate sum range with other calculations alongside

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Alright so I have an Excel sheet where I store certain numeric data.  Basically I have a column headings and date as line headings.  The data is numbers in between:

```
         column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | SUM

date1    | 1      | 5        | 3        | column1_reference * multiplier + column2_reference * multiplier...
date2    | 2      | 3        | 6        | 
date3    | 1      | 1        | 5        |
```

Now I have a reference list with the column names referring to a another set of numbers like so:

> column 1 : 40
>
> column 2 : 243
>
> column 3 : 321

So basically what I need to get is to calculate the total of each day.  Getting the number from the reference list and multiplying it with the number on data is easy (OFFSET with a named range * multiplier) but that only works with one cell.  I don't know how to apply that to a range.

So if using the previously set examples the SUM column would look like this:

> date1 SUM = (40 * 1)  +  (243 * 5) + (321 * 3)
>
> date2 SUM = (40 * 2) + (243 * 3) + (321 * 6)
>
> date3 SUM = (40 * 1) + (243 * 1) + (321 * 5)

I could do this by hand of course but my column list is rather large and it wouldn't be very dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this could be addressed with a helper row consisting of `VLOOKUPs` of the values in the reference list associated with each column name.

Then, the sums for each date would be gotten using `SUMPRODUCTs` of the values in the helper row and the amounts entered for each date.

This approach would automatically adjust when the names of the columns, or their order, changed.

In the example sheet shown below, `B2` is the first cell of the helper row; it contains the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$A$7:$B$10,2,0)
```

which is copied across the columns of data.

The first cell in the **sum** column is `E3`; its formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$D$2,B3:D3)
```

which is copied down to the bottom of the data.

While I have shown the helper row as the second row of the table, in fact it could be located anywhere on the sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the first row has numbers in `B2:D2` and you want the sum in `E2` try this formula copied down

`=SUM(MMULT(B2:D2,B$9:B$11))`

Assuming that 40, 243, 321 appears in `B9:B11`

see screenshot below:

[image]

**Edit:**

If B1:D1 and A9:A11 may not be in the same order then chuff's solution is a good one. If you want to avoid having an extra row then you need to incorporate the VLOOKUP part in the SUMPRODUCT - you can't use VLOOKUP itself because it won't return an array, LOOKUP is possible because it **does** return an array but problematic because A9:A11 would need to be sorted ascending (and even then you may have problems if some column headers don't have a match).

A way round that is to use SUMIF as a "quasi lookup", i.e. with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:D2,SUMIF(A$9:A$11,B$1:D$1,B$9:B$11))`

That will still work if second table is on another sheet or defined by OFFSET.

[Note: moot point now but in my original formula the SUM function isn't required - MMULT will work on its own]

Comment: How about if if the column names are a reference to a named range which resides in another sheet?  

The order of columns I have are not static but a drop down list.  Using your example the values in B9:B11 are not a direct reference but instead a result of OFFSET(B1,named_range,0) and in terms of the horizontal list at line 1, subject to change.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that your headers/labels would be in the same order in each location. I edited my answer to provide a solution when that isn't the case